# "Wir ziehen aus der Wohnung aus." What is the function of the first "aus" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, difference, preposition, usage

This sentence is taken from a Grammar book.

I understand that "ausziehen" is ein "Trennbare Verb" and "aus" should be placed at the end of the sentence, and it means "to move out".

DeepL translates both sentences with and without the first "aus" as "*We are moving out of the apartment.*"

So why is the first "**aus**" needed? I.e. is it correct to say...
*"Wir ziehen der Wohnung aus."*
rather than
*"Wir ziehen **aus** der Wohnung aus?"*

Or has the grammar book made a typo error?

Thanks.

Comment: Just a note regarding your use of machine translation tools: They cannot be used to identify incorrect sentences, since they will translate anything. For instance, the completely incorrect and/or nonsensical *ich habe meine Wohnung ausgezogen* is translated without any indication as *I moved out of my appartment*.

Comment: You will for sure receive meter long answers from native Germans, but I would just say that it is equal to _out of_ in the translated sentence _We are moving out of the apartment._ The second _aus_ is a part of the composite verb.

Comment: @Andra, that could (and should) be an answer.

Comment: *Ich habe meine Wohnung ausgezogen* literally means *I undressed my apartment* btw.

Comment: Contrast "Wir schauen die Wohnung an". Here the *Wohnung* is the direct object of the transitive verb *anschauen*, so no extra preposition is needed. *Ausziehen* (in the sense of moving out, as distinct from  undressing) is an intransitive verb, so it can't take a direct object: the preposition is therefore needed.

Comment: Same thing with "aufpassen": Mein Schutzengel passt auf mich auf. And I think other examples exist.

Comment: @MichaelKay: *direct object* is no helpful concept in German, see [this answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/28270).

Comment: @RHa nö, es könnt auch eine dieser berüchtigten *retractable* Wohnungen sein. Zieht die Wohnung im Angsriffsfall gleich eines Teleskops den Kopf ein, muss man die Augen Wohnung mühsam wieder ausziehen. Haste nich gesehn.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The latter "aus" is, as you correctly recognized, part of the verb "ausziehen". The former "aus" is a preposition that denotes what the speakers are moving out of. Let's break down the sentence:

> Wir ziehen aus.

> We move out.

This sentene doesn't specify what the speakers are moving out of. If we want to add this information, the part of the sentence would be

> ... aus der Wohnung ...

> ... out of the appartment ...

So, the sentence as a whole is

> Wir ziehen aus der Wohnung aus.

> We move (out) out of the appartment.

If we use the same construction with a verb that doesn't contain "aus", we could say

> Wir tragen die Koffer aus der Wohnung.

> We carry the suitcases out of the appartment.

Regarding "wir ziehen der Wohnung aus", this would be understood as to refer to another meaning of "ausziehen", being "to take off clothes". So this would be read as something like "Wir ziehen der Wohnung den Pullover aus", which doesn't make too much sense ;)

Comment: Excellent answer. "Wir ziehen der Wohnung aus" really isn't a complete German sentence in the first place. It does make grammatical sense with the addition of "den Pullover".

Comment: Unless the writer wanted to convey some metaphorical idea of stripping the house off...

Comment: @Spencer But this would need to be "Wir ziehen _die_ Wohnung aus", wouldn't it? I've heard people described as _houses_ in songs, but describing somebody as an appartment (so that the "appartment" can put on or off clothes) would be a new one to me ;)

Comment: I meant something  more like a person putting a _house_ on or off, as if it were a garment.

Comment: @Spencer That would need accusative as well, or am I mistaken? "Ich ziehe den Pullover aus" -> "Ich ziehe die Wohnung aus". But the idea is intriguing, from a storytelling / metaphorical perspective.

Comment: @Spencer like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=blk8AwFscJI)?

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck You can use that phrase to mean ‘we are stripping the house (of all furnishings)’. In that case “Wir ziehen der Wohnung aus “ makes sort of sense.

Answer (score 7):

In this case the first "aus" is related to "Wohnung", as it declares where you want to move out, while the second "aus" is related to "ziehen". "ausziehen" is the verb, but conjugated with "wir" it is "Wir ziehen aus" (we move out), not "Wir ausziehen".

So the first "aus" from "Wir ziehen **aus** der Wohnung aus." is related to "We are moving out **of** our appartment."

Hope this help´s you to understand :)

Comment: Indeed. As further illustration, one could note that depending on the region, it might also be acceptable to say "Wir ziehen von der Wohnung aus." - which makes it even clearer that that particular word is used in the same way as "of" in English.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps the easiest way for a for an English speaker to get a handle on this is to compare it with an English particle verb, which work similarly to German separable verbs. You can say "I handed my homework in." Here, "hand in" acts as a transitive verb. If you then want to add information about where the "handing in" was done, you have to use a preposition such as "in class". When you put these together you get "I handed my homework in in class." This has a repeated preposition "in" but is grammatical English. Leaving out one of the "in's" gives "I handed my homework in class," which sounds wrong to an English speaker because it's not grammatically correct; "class" has no preposition to connect it with the rest of the sentence. In the same way, *Wir ziehen der Wohnung aus.* is grammatically incorrect in German.

English is a bit squeamish about using repeated words like this, and a style guide or grammar checker might suggest rephrasing a sentence to avoid them. But they are more common in German. My favorite example is the parting phrase *Pass auf dich auf!* which is equivalent to the English "Take care of yourself!"

Comment: I think with repeated words or sounds in English it can also depend on exactly where you are, like I would never say ''It is ready already'' for reasons you mention, but people in the Bronx would say that all the time.

Comment: @Tom: Good point. People generally don't take the time to craft stylistically perfect sentences in spontaneous spoken language of any variety. So all kinds of things can happen, especially when you throw in regional accents.

Comment: Also, _Komm mit mir mit_.

Comment: In English, there are also some ''repetitions'' which are used a lot as well, ''let's see what we can see''.  In Spanish, you can say ''quedamos en quedar'' (we agree to meet).

Answer (score 2):

The German construct is not really different from the English one, it is just that *ausziehen* requires a different preposition.

In English, *to move out of* is a ["phrasal-propositional verb"](https://walton.uark.edu/business-communication-lab/Resources/downloads/Multi-word_Verbs.pdf). The core is *to move out*, a phrasal verb. It is a verb that assumes a new, often metaphorical meaning when it is combined with a particle: *To break **down,** to put **off,*** and *to move **out.*** German, in its characteristic fashion, makes a compound word of phrasal verbs: ***zusammen**brechen, **ab**weisen,* and, finally,  ***aus**ziehen.*

Additionally, *to move out* requires a preposition — that's the "prepositional" part —, namely *of:* *To move out **of*** something/somewhere. The German *ausziehen* simply requires a different preposition, that's all: ***Aus** [etwas] ausziehen.* The duplicated *aus* may seem weird until we remember similar constructs in English: *To **in**still reason **in** him,* *to **in**vest **in** stock.*

The languages are often remarkably similar.

Answer (score 1):

> So why is the first "aus" needed?

Like the other answers noted, the preposition is necessary to denote the object. There is also "ausziehen" without a preposition, but that uses the object in accusative case, and has a different meaning: "*Wir ziehen den Pullover aus*" - "*We take off the pullover*". It doesn't make sense to use this form for an apartment ("*Wir ziehen die Wohnung aus.*") :-)

> I.e. is it correct to say... "Wir ziehen der Wohnung aus."

No. That would be as incorrect as the English "*We move out the apartment*".

However, you can omit the second "aus":

"*Wir ziehen aus der Wohnung (aus).*"

- "*We move (out) from the apartment.*" / "*We move (out) out of the apartment.*"

In this case the verb "ziehen" is understood as a short form for "umziehen", although it also has the meaning of being part of a procession ("*umherziehen*", for which I don't know a direct translation). You'd more customarily say something like

"*Wir ziehen aus der Wohnung in eine andere (um).*"

- "*We move from the apartment into another.*"